# Discord bot post multiple results

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

First time using stackoverflow. It is a bot made to post result whenever new episode of show in search list gets added on nyaa.si. I want bot to post result only once for every episode but bot post same episode multiple time in different time frames. It gets fixed for while after I restart the bot.
The code to add show to search list.

```
async addShow(msg) {
        const regex = /"(.+?)" "(.+?)"(?: "(.+?)")?/g;
        const found = regex.exec(msg.content);
        if (found === null) {
            await msg.channel.send(`Invalid new syntax:\n${COMMAND_CHARACTER} new \"show search phrase\" \"MALURL\" \"attribute regex\" (optional last)`);
            return;
        }

        let [f, search, url, reg] = found;
        let count = await this.db.get('search').last().value();
        if (_.isUndefined(count)) {
            count = 0;
        }
        else {
            count = count.id;
        }
        await this.db.get('search').push({id: count + 1, search, url, regex: reg}).write();
        logger.info(`New show has been added to the searchlist - ${search} - ${url} for server ${this.guildID}`);
        await msg.channel.send("Saved!");
    }
```

The code to search

```
async searchShow(id, query, channel = null, OG = null) {
        const results = await this.nyaa.getResults(query);
        if (!results.length) {
            return;
        }

        logger.info(`Results found for ${query}: ${results.length}`);
        const embedFunction = this.getRichEmbed.bind(this);

        for (let i of results) {
            const item = await this.db.get('rss').find({guid: i.guid}).value();
            if (!_.isUndefined(item)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (await this.postShow(embedFunction, i, channel, OG)) {
                await this.db.get('rss').push({...i, searchID: id}).write();
            }
        }
    }
```

Code to post result when new episode comes.

```
async postShow(embedFunc, item, channel = null, og = null, channelType = NYAA_UPDATES) {
        if (channel === null) {
            channel = await this.getGuildChannel(channelType);

            if (!channel) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
            const title = (og !== null ? og.title ?? item.title : item.title);
            const embed = await embedFunc(item, title);

            if (og !== null) {
                const img = og.image ?? null;
                if (img) {
                    embed.setThumbnail(img);
                }

                const url = og.url ?? null;
                if (url) {
                    embed.setURL(url);
                }
            }

            let retryCounter = 0;

            logger.info(`Posting new result for ${title} with guid ${item.guid} for server ${this.guildID}`);
            while (true) {
                try {
                    await channel.send(embed);
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        resolve(true);
                    }, 2000);
                    break;
                }
                catch (e) {
                    logger.warn(`An error has occured while posting: ${e.toString()}, retrying (${++retryCounter} in 5 seconds`);
                    await new Promise((res) => {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            res();
                        }, 5000);
                    });
                    if (retryCounter > 10) {
                        resolve(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Also one who wrote most of code was different person and I only added few additional function here and there which doesn't affect the code much. One who wrote most of core code had to leave discord so I was left to host the bot which I am hosting at repl.it. It will be great help to know whether the problem is with the code or not.

Comment: Also I am using json as database where search list are kept. Also where when new episode of any show from search list gets added gets pushed which is later embedded and posted as result on discord.

Comment: If the error is not within the code, then possibly there are two active discord hooks

Answer (score 1):

As Julian Kleine mentioned above, the most common reason a bot posts multiple times is if you are running multiple instances of the host. Close all instances of command prompt, and check task manager to see if any other hidden instances are running in the background.

Comment: As I am hosting a bot in repll.it I don't know how to check if multiple instances are running.

Comment: Ah, I have no experience with that, sorry - try and look at the docs